# Find a point whose entries satisfy a hyperbola equation

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I want to find the entries of a point $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$ which
satisfy this equation:

$(x_i - x_{a,i}) (x_j - x_{a,j}) = A_{ij}$,

where point $\mathbf{x}_a$ and a $(3\times3)$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ are given.

If we introduce the vector $\Delta \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_a$, we can also write the equation in terms of this expression:

$\mathbf{x} \otimes \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}$.

Is there a way to find an equation that gives me the entries of $\mathbf{x}$?

Edit:

Matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric.

Comment: If you mean for the equalities to hold for all $i,j$ combinations, you have a system of $9$ equations with $3$ unknowns, which will generally have no solutions, unless you have additional knowledge about $A_{ij}$ that's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric, so I guess that gives me $6$ equations and $3$ unknowns...

Comment: Symmetric is not enough, you also need $\,A_{ii} \ge 0\,$ and $\,A_{ij}^2=A_{ii}A_{jj}\,$ for a solution to exist.

Comment: @Flose You should add in your question that $A$ is symmetric.